# IE 9 compability with HTML 5

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-9

I create a website http://www.gkduniya.com . With Mozilla and chrome the category section is OK. But with IE 9, category section misplaced. Plz check it for details. I am using the below CSS code to make the gradientbox:

```
 .gradientBoxesWithOuterShadows { 
  height:auto;
  width: 240px; 
   padding: 20px;
  background-color: white; 

/* outer shadows  (note the rgba is red, green, blue, alpha) */
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(23, 69, 88, .5);

/* rounded corners */
 -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-border-radius: 7px; 
  border-radius: 7px;

 /* gradients */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
 color-stop(0%, white), color-stop(15%, white), color-stop(100%, #D7E9F5)); 
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, white 55%, #D5E4F3 130%); 
 }
```

Plz help so that it also work with IE 9.

Comment: On my IE9 (9.0.8), the Category section is placed correctly. The only thing not working is the gradient, for obvious reasons (you need to add the unprefixed box-shadow & gradient).

Comment: Make sure that IE9 *is* running in IE9/9 mode. It has a ridiculous tendency to "downgrade" .. (ever see the results of ACID 2/3 tests in IE8 or below?)

Comment: (Also, that page has a *ridiculous* number of JavaScript errors. Might also want to run the markup through a validator; who knows what else is wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

Oops! This is wrong:

```
<!DOCKTYPE HTML>
```

Such an invalid DOCTYPE will set IE9 to run in "Quirks Mode Document" unless changed/forced by the IE9 Developer Tools (or other random Windows settings).

**Fix the page so it is valid markup** and [use a validator to *ensure* it is valid](http://validator.w3.org). (Interestingly enough the w3c validator guesses it as HTML5 while IE9 marks the page default as quirks. Also, I can only get IE9 to "look significantly wrong" in IE9/IE7 mode.)

Also fix the JavaScript errors so it doesn't poop a bunch of error messages which are displayed so annoyingly in IE :(

Comment: In The index page it is <!DOCTYPE html> , yes in other pages it is  <!DOCKTYPE HTML>. It present i am working on the index page. but get that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, just add the unprefixed `box-shadow` and you're good to go. Similarly, add the unprefixed `gradient` for the background.

Answer (score 0):

Add un prefixed `box-shadow` to your css and for Gradient issues  add

```
-ms-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, white 55%, #D5E4F3 130%); /* for IE-10 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#FFF', EndColorStr='#D5E4F3'); /* IE6–IE9 */
linear-gradient(top, white 0%, white 55%, #D5E4F3 130%); /* for all */
```

For further easy development refer  [CSS Gradient Background Maker](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/default.html)

Comment: thanks for help. I am new to languages. can to tell me exactly where to put  those codes in the CSS file.

Comment: Copy the above three lines and paste just before closing `.gradientBoxesWithOuterShadows{` . . .  } in your CSS

Comment: Your Site has issues with alignment,  Either **replace** your `style.css` with [Width-1080](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/40690073/GK/gkstyle_unchanged.css) for maintaining current width & site center aligned or **replace** [width-all-screens](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/40690073/GK/gkstyle.css) css for all monitor support, many users still use 1024x780 CRT Monitors.